# Iterating over an Groovy object that may be a String or a String Array

Tags: grails, groovy

Using Grails and the scenario is if I have an object passed in from an HTTP request and I iterate through the object and grab all possible objects as in:

```
if (params.colors) {
  for (String color in params.colors) {
    println color
  }
}
```

If a [Ljava.lang.String is passed in (i.e., params.colors = ["blue","green","yellow"]) then your output is as expected:

```
blue
green
yellow
```

But if params.colors = "blue", then of course, groovy will tokenize "blue" and you'll get the output:

```
b
l
u
e
```

I suppose I should be checking to see if it's already an array. Unless I'm approaching this wrong or there is a groovy way of doing it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can access the colors param as a list using the `list` method on the `params` object:

```
for (String color in params.list('colors')) {
  println color
}
```

This way, it won't matter if you action is called like `/your_action?colors=red` or `/your_action?colors=red&colors=green` or even with no colors param at all (that's why i left out the `if`), `params.list('colors')` will always return a list :)